# MYSQL Query Help JOIN Tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having some trouble with a query and hopefully someone can guide me through this? I think this should be possible to accomplish. I have two tables. Table A stores hours and Table B stores driving time. I am trying to get all the people who have more than 6 hours worked in a day which I was able to do. But I also need to get the driving time for that specific day where they did more than 6 hours in a day. I hope I make sense. This is the query that I am using right now and is working to get everyone who worked more than 6 hours a day I just can get the minutes as well. The driving time is store in table B called ies_mileage and the field is duration. I have tried several things with no success.

```
SELECT 
    wk_date,
    full_name, 
    SUM(hours) AS HOURS 
FROM `ies_weekly` 
    LEFT JOIN infant_specialist 
        ON ies_weekly.is_id = infant_specialist.is_id 
WHERE wk_date BETWEEN '2015-01-16' AND '2015-01-31' 
GROUP BY 
    DAY(wk_date), 
    ies_weekly.is_id 
HAVING SUM(hours) > 6 
ORDER BY full_name  ASC
```

This is working, when I tried to add the duration the total gets messed up and it's no longer accurate. here is what i've tried

```
SELECT 
    wk_date,
    full_name, 
    SUM(hours) AS HOURS, 
    SUM(duration) AS minutes 
FROM 
    `ies_weekly` 
    LEFT JOIN infant_specialist 
        ON ies_weekly.is_id = infant_specialist.is_id 
    LEFT JOIN ies_mileage 
        ON ies_weekly.wk_date = ies_mileage.mil_date 
        AND ies_weekly.is_id = ies_mileage.ies_id 
WHERE wk_date BETWEEN '2015-01-16' AND '2015-01-31' 
GROUP BY 
    DAY(wk_date), 
    ies_weekly.is_id 
HAVING SUM(hours) > 6
ORDER BY full_name  ASC
```

Comment: Perhaps you can supply sample data and desired results.  As is, it's difficult to understand what's wrong with your second query.

Comment: the results from the second query are not accurate i.e. 1st query tells me on 2015-01-22 were 7 hours for user 10 which is correct 2nd query gives me 35 hours for 2015-01-22 same user 10 which is incorrect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT full_name, wk_date, SUM(hours) HOURS,
    (Select Sum(duration)
     From ies_mileage
     Where mil_date = w.wk_date
         and ies_id = w.is_id) DrivingTime
FROM ies_weekly w
    LEFT JOIN infant_specialist i
     ON i.is_id = w.is_id 
WHERE wk_date BETWEEN '2015-01-16' AND '2015-01-31' 
GROUP BY DAY(wk_date), w.is_id 
HAVING SUM(hours) > 6 
ORDER BY full_name ASC
```